# What is a single word to use in place of 'Costing a large number of lives'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, synonyms, sentence

If I'm writing a sentence such as

"The second World War was the single most wasteful and (**Costing a large number of lives/ having a high death toll**) war in the History of Mankind.

What single word/phrase can I use to convey the ideas in the bracketed portion.

Comment: Don't try and use a single word. Don't use *wasteful*, either. That's inappropriately funny and does not mean what you want it to mean. And never Capitalize random Words in the Middle Of sentences.

Comment: heavy casualty?

Comment: Can you elaborate; how wasteful can be taken as disrespectful ? I would like to understand. The context which I meant was "The second world war was wasteful (in terms of resources)"

Answer (score 1):

*Deadly* would fit quite well.

[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=deadly)

> 1. Causing or tending to cause death

It is used in similar situations:

> The Rwandan genocide likewise ended with a military solution, in this
> case a Tutsi victory. (But this became the seed for the most **deadly**
> war on earth since 1945, the Congo War of 1998 -- 2006.) (Game Theory
> ([Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/game-theory/)))
>
> Vietnam veterans Antonio Porres and Frankie Infante also enlisted
> together, fought the length of that **deadly** war and miraculously
> returned intact. ( Houston Chronicle , LORI RODRIGUEZ, HOMES VS.
> HERITAGE;; The relationship between a subdivision and a cemetery is
> side-by-side but hardly eye-to-eye)
>
> OUR COUNTRY HAS BEEN AT WAR on two fronts, but only the war abroad was
> declared. It is time for you and me to make our leaders confront the
> equally **deadly** war raging in our cities, towns, and rural and
> suburban areas, which poses as much of a threat to the nation's
> security and economic prosperity as any foreign enemy. # Every time a
> cruise missile landed and each time an AWACS plane took off in the
> Persian Gulf, it was hard to restrain myself from shouting: " My God,
> how many Head Start slots was that? How much money in housing for
> homeless children could have been provided?" (Mother Jones, Edelman,
> M.W., Kids first! (cover story), Vol. 16 Issue 3, p31)

Answer (score 1):

**"Fatal,"** **"lethal,"** **"destructive,"** **"death-dealing,"** **"mortal,"** **"murderous,"** **"homicidal,"** **"bloody,"** and *many* others would work in this situation.

These are the **applicable** definitions of the words I listed above:

*All of the following definitions are from [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition)]*

**Fatal** - "Causing death."

**Lethal** - "Harmful or destructive."

**Destructive** - "Causing great and irreparable harm or damage."

**Death-dealing** - "Capable of causing death."

**Mortal** - "Causing or liable to cause death; fatal." *OR* "(of a battle) fought to the death."

**Murderous** - "(of an action, event, or plan) involving murder or extreme violence."

**Homicidal** - "Capable of or tending toward murder; murderous."

**Bloody** - "Involving or characterized by bloodshed or cruelty."

---

*There are **many** other words that could be applied to this situation.  Run any of these words through a thesaurus and you will find many alternatives.  **Also, the use of the word "wasteful" is disrespectful in this context; you should remove/replace it.***

Comment: Can you elaborate; how wasteful can be taken as disrespectful ? I would like to understand. The context which I meant was "The second world war was wasteful (in terms of resources)"

Comment: @VigneswaraPrabhu As you said, wasteful is used chiefly in terms of resources.  Instead of talking about the wasted resources, you should maybe choose a word that describes the magnitude of the war.  It is disrespectful because you are talking about wasting resources in the same breath as the *millions* of lives that were ended during the war.  Personally, I wouldn't talk about the "waste" of WW2 anywhere near the fatalities.

Comment: @VigneswaraPrabhu Was the rest of my answer satisfactory? If so, please upvote and accept it.  Otherwise, I'd be glad to find some other words if the ones I provided don't work.